# How to get SonarQube running to analyze a PHP project?

Tags: php, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I want to assess SonarQube as a source code inspection tool.

The project is hosted in a git repository, and I want to SonarQube to check my PHP project on each commit.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code and more especially : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+an+Analyzer ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got a basic instance of [SonarQube via docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/). (The current version of sonar cube is 6.7 -- yet I do not know if the steps remain the same. This answer takes into account 5.1.)

Run the container:

```
sudo docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube:5.1
```

This provides with a standard install of SonarQube accessable at

```
http://localhost:9000/
```

I can login via username and passoword `admin`, and install the PHP component via:

Settings > System > Update Center

(or: `http://localhost:9000/updatecenter` )

and search for PHP and install.

There I can add PHP and after restart of the SonarQube server, (I did it via `docker stop container_id`, `container start container_id`), the extension is loaded.

The server will not run your tests. It will only display the results.

You will need a machine dedicated to work as your `sonar-runner`, for a quick start you may use your local dev machine and your local checkout from bitbucket. Install the sonar-runner on that machine.

Download the sonar runner via:

```
 $ wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/runner/sonar-runner-dist/2.4/sonar-runner-dist-2.4.zip
```

and extracted it to:

```
 ~/programs/sonar-runner-2.4
```

In this directory, there you find a file `conf/sonar-runner.properties` that should contain:

```
#Configure here general information about the environment, such as SonarQube DB details for example
#No information about specific project should appear here

#----- Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

#----- PostgreSQL
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar

#----- MySQL
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8

#----- Oracle
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE

#----- Microsoft SQLServer
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor

#----- Global database settings
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

#----- Default source code encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

#----- Security (when 'sonar.forceAuthentication' is set to 'true')
sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=admin
```

Go into your project's root directory and create a file called `sonar-project.properties`:

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=yourProjectKey
# this is the name displayed in the SonarQube UI
sonar.projectName=yourProject
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# Since SonarQube 4.2, this property is optional if sonar.modules is set. 
# If not set, SonarQube starts looking for source code from the directory containing 
# the sonar-project.properties file.
sonar.sources=./classes/,./tests/

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

I then ran:

```
 your/projects/dir$: ~/programs/sonar-runner-2.4/bin/sonar-runner
```

You will then see an new entry at your SonarCube dashboard.

Comment: Just a note, the file created into your project whit the properties of it should name sonar-project.properties or it doesn't work (i dont know if there is another way).

Answer (score 0):

Get the following:

- OpenJDK:      7u55+ of 8
- MySQL:        5.1 t/m 5.7
- SonarQube:    http://dist.sonar.codehaus.org/sonarqube-5.1.zip
- Sonar Runner:     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/runner/sonar-runner-dist/2.4/sonar-runner-dist-2.4.zip

Do the following:

- Installation: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing

Setup SonarRunner:

```
#Configure here general information about the environment, such as     SonarQube DB details for example
#No information about specific project should appear here

#----- Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=http://14.3.1.4:9000

#----- PostgreSQL
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar

#----- MySQL
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://14.3.1.2:3306/sonarqube?   useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8

#----- Oracle
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE

#----- Microsoft SQLServer
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor

#----- Global database settings
sonar.jdbc.username=sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.password=sonarqube

#----- Default source code encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

#----- Security (when 'sonar.forceAuthentication' is set to 'true')
#sonar.login=admin
#sonar.password=admin
```

Clone a git repo in the var/www folder on the server where sonar is at. 
Then add a configurationfile in the project you want to check called `sonar-project.properties`. Here is an Symfony example:

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=yoursite.dev.nl.project
sonar.projectName=Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.projectBaseDir=/var/www/your_project
# Folder being analysed. 
sonar.sources=symfony/src  

# Language (Only when it is a single language)
sonar.language=php
# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```